# Number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 17$ if

Tags: combinatorics

> How many integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 17$ are there if...

a) $x_i \ge -1$

b) $-1 \le x_i \le 5$

My solution for a) is $\binom{24}{21}$ and for b) it is $\binom{24}{21} - \binom{4}{1} \binom{17}{14} +\binom{4}{2} \binom{10}{7} - \binom{4}{3} \binom{3}{0} =20$

Just wondering if I've done these correctly as I can't find any solutions to cases where the integers can be negative as well on this site or in my text.

Comment: By making the change of variable from $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=17$ where each $-1\leq x_i\color{grey}{\leq 5}$ to instead $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=21$ where each $0\leq y_i\color{grey}{\leq 6}$ using the substitution $y_i=x_i+1$ you now no longer have any negative numbers to worry about.  At a glance it appears as though you did it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes!